# Pandas python reversing the the values and rows for column within a dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

How do I reverse the rows in a column using pandas, as in I want to change the value of the last row, `row 4` and switch it with `row 0`. so instead of `row:0` equaling 1 it would equal to 10.

Code associated with the code down below:

```
import pandas as pd
data =pd.read_csv('input.csv')
#printing out a single column
set_val =data['sets']
set_val
```

sets dataset(row number, value) output:

```
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       10
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need swap first and last value of column `sets` use:

```
data.loc[data.index[[0, -1]], 'sets'] = data.loc[data.index[[-1, 0]], 'sets'].to_numpy()
```

Or:

```
data.iloc[[0, -1], data.columns.get_loc('sets')] = 
data.iloc[[-1, 0], data.columns.get_loc('sets')].to_numpy()
print (data)
   sets
0    10
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     1
```

If need reverse all values:

```
data1 = data.iloc[::-1]
print (data1)
   sets
4    10
3     4
2     3
1     2
0     1
```

Comment: Is there a way i can reverse all the data's without also reversing the rows, like `row 0 =10` , `row 1 =4` , `row 2 =3` , `row 3 =2` and `row 4 =1`